# Adding libcurl.lib in vrxhdr command

Tags: libcurl, verifone

I am trying to run a secure HTTP connection from a Verifone C680 POS terminal. Libcurl was added in Verix EOSSDK version 2.12.2.0 and i am using this resource from Verix SDK.

All code i write was compiled and linked fine. But, when i run the app in the terminal it was logged (log debug) that "libcurl.l" (without "ib" in file name extension) wasn´t in the terminal.

A little part of the log:

```
19 17:28:40.150 sgpi(N:/SSL2.LIB,2,1) -1:abs=0 -1:rel=0
19 17:28:40.150 sgpi(N:/LIBCURL.L.LIB,2,1) -1:abs=0 -1:rel=0
19 17:28:40.150 -- Lib N:/LIBCURL.L absent
```

The file libcurl.lib are loaded in terminal group 15.

That seems the command

```
$(VRXSDK)\bin\vrxhdr -s 256000 -h 256000 
-lvoyns.lib=/voyns.lib -lGCFG.lib=/GCFG.lib -lCSUM.lib=/CSUM.lib 
-lVCS.lib=/VCS.lib -lEMV.lib=/EMV.lib -lEMOD.lib=/EMOD.lib -lESCR.lib=?/ESCR.lib -lnet.lib=N:/net.lib -lelog.lib=N:/elog.lib -lceif.lib=N:/ceif.lib 
-llibcurl.lib=N:/libcurl.lib -lssl2.lib=N:/ssl2.lib 
-lctls.lib=N:/ctls.lib $(OutDir)\MyApp.out
```

was truncating the libcurl file name. Why? And how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post the output of `vrxhdr MyApp.out`?

Comment: Did you manage to link it properly?